# Remove Duplicates of 2 columns in Tableau

Tags: database, tableau-api

I need to remove the duplicates in a file in tableau. The columns are `ACCOUNT_ID` and `Denial_Reason`.

Remove duplicates if the `ACCOUNT_ID` and `Denial_Reason` are the same!

I have tried using Create Calculated Field -> COUNTD 
However I think this would only pertain to a single column.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but `COUNTD()` can take any expression. So you could do something like `COUNTD([ACCOUNT_ID] + [Denial_Reason])` to get the count of unique combinations of `ACCOUNT_ID` and `Denial_Reason`.

Comment: sample would help to give perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FIXED` level of detail expression:

```
{FIXED [ACCOUNT_ID], [Denial_Reason] : MIN([ACCOUNT_ID] + " " + [Denial_Reason])}
```

Drop this on Text or Rows and you'll get every unique combination of `ACCOUNT_ID` and `Denial_Reason`.